# Why is echo matching some files twice?

Tags: bash, shell, echo, brace-expansion

```
$ touch file{1..12}

$ echo *e{1..12}
file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 file7 file8 file9 file10 file11 file12

$ echo *{1..12}
file1 file11 file12 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 file7 file8 file9 file10 file11 file12
```

I don't understand why this is happening. Please can someone explain?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Braces are not wildcard patterns. Check the [documentation of bash expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions): braces are expanded very early in the process, and wildcard patterns are expanded in the last step¹.

Initially, the command consists of two words `echo`, `*{1..12}`. After brace expansion, the command contains 13 words: `echo`, `*1`, `*2`, …, `*12`. Then wildcard patterns are expanded. `*1` expands to the list of file names ending in `1`, which includes not only `file1` but also `file11` (which is sorted afterwards in lexicographic order). Likewise `*2` expands to `file12` and `file2` (in this order). So you get `echo`, `file1`, `file11`, `file12`, `file2`, and then the other wildcards that matched a single file: `file3`, `file4`, …, `file12`.

¹  <sub>Next to last, if you follow the manual's description, but “quote removal” isn't really a thing — quotes are parsed earlier than the expansion process.</sub>